# DSolveValue::deqx problem?

Tags: differential-equations

I tried to solve this 1D wave equation, with SolveValue but it doesn't work, and I don't know why? if anyone can help me, please

```
t1 = 2;
indicator[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, 0 < x < 1/2}}, 0];
(*problème du controle*)
E1 = D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] - D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] == 
   indicator[
     x]*  (Cos[π t1] + Cos[3 π t1] + Cos[5 π t1] + 
      2 Cos[3 π t1] Cos[2 π x] + 
      2 Cos[5 π t1] Cos[2 π x] + 
      2 Cos[5 π t1] Cos[4 π x] + Sin[π t1] + 
      2 (Cos[2 π t1] Cos[π x] + 
         Cos[π x] Sin[2 π t1]) + Sin[3 π t1] + 
      2 Cos[2 π x] Sin[3 π t1] + 
      2 (Cos[4 π t1] Cos[π x] + 
         Cos[4 π t1] Cos[3 π x] + 
         Cos[π x] Sin[4 π t1] + 
         Cos[3 π x] Sin[4 π t1]) + Sin[5 π t1] + 
      2 Cos[2 π x] Sin[5 π t1] + 
      2 Cos[4 π x] Sin[
        5 π t1]) Sin[π x];                                    \

(*données initiales propres*)
ic = {f[x, 0] == 
    Sin[π x] + Sin[2 π x] + Sin[3 π x] + Sin[4 π x] + 
     Sin[5 π x], 
   Derivative[0, 1][f][x, 0] ==  π Sin[π x] + 
     2 π Sin[2 π x] + 3 π Sin[3 π x] + 
     4 π Sin[4 π x] + 5 π Sin[5  π x]};
(*Condition aux bord de Dirichlet*)
bcc = {u[0, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 0};
(*résolution analytique de l'équation*)
sol5 = DSolveValue[{E1, ic, bcc}, u[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 12}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You have some `f`s in your `ic` which I think should be `u`.

```
ic = {u[x, 0] == 
    Sin[π x] + Sin[2 π x] + Sin[3 π x] + Sin[4 π x] + 
     Sin[5 π x], 
   Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] ==  π Sin[π x] + 
     2 π Sin[2 π x] + 3 π Sin[3 π x] + 
     4 π Sin[4 π x] + 5 π Sin[5 π x]};
```

Once I changed these I also changed `DSolveValue` to `NDSolveValue` because it was taking too long.

```
sol5 = NDSolveValue[{E1, ic, bcc}, u[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 12}];
Plot3D[sol5, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 12}, PlotPoints -> 50, AxesLabel -> {x, t, u}]
```

[image: u solution plot]

If you want to vary `t` in a `Manipulate` (replaced with `s` here) you can do this:

```
Manipulate[Plot[sol5 /. t -> s, {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {x, u}], {s, 0, 12}]
```

[image]

Comment: yeh, it's working, thank you